# How to make an input a default input field of a view?

Tags: javascript, angular, input, frontend

In the Angular app there are multiple views that have various inputs. When the user goes into a view, he needs to click the input field to type in the value. On a mobile device it is expected behaviour since the user would have to open keyboard widget to type in, so it is good he needs to click the field to type data in. But on a computer there is no need for a keyboard widget to open. User can type straight away. My question is: how to make a input field "default", so that when the user starts typing on a computer (or any other device with keyboard) the "default" input field will focus and fetch the incoming typed in string? Something like:

```
<input defaultInputOfAView="true"></input>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `autofocus` to achieve it.

```
<input defaultInputOfAView="true" autofocus></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a very nice solution (besides `autofocus` that triggers only once):

```
<div>
  <input #myInputRef>
  {{myInputRef.focus()}}
</div>
```